# Is it okay to have wide variations within one of the classes for binary classification tasks?

Tags: neural-networks, classification

Say I am using a convolutional network to classify pictures of my face versus anyone else's face in the world.

So let's take 10000 pictures of me, and 10000 pictures of other people.

And let's do three experiments where we train a binary classifier:

**1)** The 10000 "other" pictures are of 1 other person.

**2)** The 10000 "other" pictures are of ~10 other people (approximately balanced, so about 1000 pictures per person).

**3)** The 10000 "other" pictures are of ~10000 other people.

I only have one question but here are some different perspectives on it:

- Are any of these cases categorically harder to solve than the others?
- Are they the same difficulty, or close?
- Are there known considerations to make when tuning the model for each
  of the cases? (like maybe case (3) has a sharper minimum in the loss
  function than (1) so we need to use a different optimisation approach)

Comment: It depends on the context whether it's "harder". Are each of these options representative of what the network will see in testing data? Which ever matches the testing data most closely will have the best result.